# Import product using async rest bulk API and RabbitMQ

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.4, magento2-cloud, rabbit-mq, bulk

We are working on a shop with about 7k products that are provided by several messy CSV. We decided to parse data from all these CSV and try to use async bulk api for import products, basically following these tutorials

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/bulk-configurable-product/config-product-intro.html
- https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Create-a-configurable-product-%5BWeb-API-Tutorial%5D (this reference doesn't use bulk api but was useful to understand better how to build Json)

We chose this way because we read great things about performance use this method and since we are working on a Magento Cloud Pro we asked to enable RabbitMq service.

After launch the import process we found however that the queue processing is very slow (about 1 product/sec)

Furthermore after sending the list of all products we perform two more api calls to configure configurable products but it happens that this queue is being process with the previous one and the system tries to associate some products that maybe are still not imported.

It's the first time that we use RabbitMq and this approach for import and we are sure that there is something wrong in pur procedure.

- Did someone have experience on bulk api and point us to the right direction?
- Are there some settings Magento side or RabbitMq side that are suggested? (we left all with default settings)
- How is possible to have a  graphic interface for rabbit mq to monitor queues on Magento Cloud?

I hope someone could help us because it's seem strange that for importing 7k products, 3-4 hours are necessary... or maybe all that glitters is not gold and async bulk api are not so great as they told!

Comment: I hope you found a solution in the mean time. The RabbitMQ has a GUI as well, which is accessible via web. The problem you mentioned is the same problem we have to struggle with right now. We have 19k products, 4 storeviews and about 20 additional attributes. It takes roughly 20 hours to import (with images via base64 tho). Our client is not able to just deliver "new and updated" products, therefore we need some help here as well. Did you got any further on this topic?

Comment: We are facing the same issue, the operation is terribly slow. Could you figure out how to speed it up?